# TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDidMount' of null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to assert a method is called with the correct props in my `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    const { fetchContentForUser } = this.props
    fetchContentForUser({ userId: '6ae42468-83f2-0bf39a917713' })
  }
```

My test looks like this

```
let props
let wrapper
      beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
          fetchContentForUser: jest.fn(),
          loading: false
        }
      })

          it('should call fetchContentForUser on mount', () => {
            wrapper = shallow(<LandingComponent {...props} />)
            wrapper.update()
            wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()

            expect(props.fetchContentForUser).toHaveBeenCalled()
          })
```

However I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDidMount' of null
```

How can I assert this method is called? I am using Jest / Enzyme.

Comment: are you using `enzyme-adapter-react-16`?

Comment: Yes, using the latest version of Create React App also.

Comment: `wrapper.instance()` shouldn't be null in case LandingComponent  is really a class. And you don't need to call `componentDidMount` manually, it's already called by Enzyme. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's not shown how LandingComponent  is defined and imported.